Change all outdated blockexplorer.com links
A lot of useful old answers point to https://www.blockexplorer.com/ which is now covering the "Joseon Blockchain" and not Bitcoin. What should the URLs be changed to?

There are a number of choices, however I'm reluctant to list specific sites since that might be seen as an endorsement.
Where appropriate, it might be useful to edit pertinent questions with a note indicating that blockexplorer no longer provides Bitcoin blockchain data.
